# Editing fields required in the WooCommerce / WordPress registration form

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates, forms

I can't seem to find the template file or find the setting within WooCommerce to amend the fields requested in the registration form for a WordPress site.

I did not set up the form to begin with and have been brought in on this project.

Does anyone know where this form is saved and how I can go about removing the 'Organisation' field? It is a required field making this more than just hide it with CSS jobby.

I'm here to answer any questions / fetch any helpful information about my set up.

Thanks, Jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these were custom fields set up within the functions.php file.

Thanks, Jason.